# Change View Color based on another View's Color

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple iOS app written in Swift that chooses a random background color every time a button is pushed. There is a "Credits" button in the view that acts as a modal segue to another view. How would I go about setting the color of the second view based on whatever color the background is in the first view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive this like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Load View") {
        // pass data to next view
       let viewController:ViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as  ViewController
       viewController.view.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass color from first controller to second. below is the snippet.

```
 let destinationVC:ViewControllerClass = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerClass
destinationVC.color = view.backgroundColor
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass some arguments to the view controller you're presenting or pushing by overriding `prepareForSegue` method :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {        
     if let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? MySecondViewControllerClass {
        secondViewController.view.backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor   
     }
}
```

You can find more infos available about `prepareForSegue` on [UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:) from Apple.